# Saving all responses from a specific URL to disk while browsing

Tags: web-browser, scripting

I am looking for a versatile solution that allows me to capture and save all the responses from a specific URL to disk while I am browsing, with no restrictions on the browser, external programs, or programming languages used.

I want to be able to record the complete HTTP responses, including headers, status codes, and response bodies, and store them locally for further analysis, archiving, or offline access. The solution should ideally work seamlessly

The solution should ideally capture responses in real-time while I interact with the website, without requiring manual intervention for each response (Ideally)